# Expiration to delete a record of a Custom Object, Workflow Rule or Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, workflow

Is it possible to have a Workflow Rule or Trigger delete a record of a custom object upon a certain date?

Comment: @EricSSH How would I do that? A cursory Googling didn't return much valuable information.

Comment: You can't schedule triggers.

Comment: Ya oops, this should get you started http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a Scheduled Apex class that runs on a certain day, looks for the record and performs a DML delete statement. Here is some helpful info about Scheduled Apex: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative approach, you could write a workflow time-based action that triggers a field update on the record, and have a trigger delete the record at that time. Example:

Fields:

- Field: Delete__c (Checkbox), Default Unchecked
- Field: Deletion_Date__c (DateTime), set however you like

Workflow:

- Workflow: Criteria (whatever you need)
- Workflow Time Based Action: (0 days after Deletion_Date__c)
- Workflow Field Update: Set Delete__c to checked

Trigger:

```
trigger deleteRecords on Object__c(after update) {
    Object__c[] deletions = new Object[0];
    for(Object__c record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.Delete__c) {
            deletions.add(new Object__c(Id=record.Id));
        }
    }
    delete deletions;
}
```

This avoids the hassle of setting up a scheduler class and remembering to schedule the class and monitor it to make sure it doesn't crash, at the slight expense of longer save times (immeasurably so).

Comment: I like this method due to the amount of time it ends up saving, and the process it easily automates.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of issue, the time based workflow doesn't seem to be firing for some reason. It's set to evaluate to true when the expiration date is less than or equal to today. Any ideas?

Comment: Rules only evaluate on save. The criteria should reflect when the record should be queued for future execution. In thus case, the criteria should be "when expiration date is not null"

Comment: This should evaluate against any record for that object I save, right? I saved an older one with today's date and it didn't trigger the field change

Comment: Depends on your workflow conditions and trigger. You'd probably need to clear the expiration date, then rest it again, I'd wager.

Comment: So apparently DML statements cannot happen on triggers.

Comment: @CodyBeaner I forgot about that. It's true you can't trigger on records in Trigger.new, but you *can* still affect those records. Updated this code to reflect the changes needed.

Comment: Well we can make any number of statements, but simply a DML delete will not happen on trigger.new or trigger.old.

Comment: @CodyBeaner Correct, you can't work on the literal records in Trigger.old and Trigger.new. However, you can construct a new record in memory that matches an ID of the record in the trigger and successfully delete it. Here's an example I wrote in my dev org just now that proves this: `trigger deleteOnUpdate on Account (after update) {
    delete new Account(Id=Trigger.new[0].Id);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a record using a workflow rule.

Triggers are fired when certain event occurs like insert , update and delete.So its not a good practice to delete record in trigger.

If u want to delete a record on certain dates or conditions you should use the scheduled apex to collect the record and delete it .

If you want more clarification ask here. I will help you out as soon as possible. http://forcesnippet.tumblr.com/ask